# How do I divide a dollar amount by a time stamp

Tags: time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to figure out how many dollars & cents were made or lost per minute. So for instance, if I have $10 and it took me 10 minutes (00:10:00) to acquire it, I want to know how much I made per minute:

```
Dollars & cents made per minute = $10 / 0:10:00
```

How do I implement this in google sheets?

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion: factorise everything out to a single common number. Don't do dollars and cents, just do cents (then convert back to dollars and cents afterwards). Don't do minutes and seconds, just do seconds - then convert back to minutes and seconds afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=A2/1440/TIMEVALUE(B2)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: where does 1440 come from?

Comment: @NeilHawke 24 hours * 60 minutes = 1440 minutes/day

Answer (score 0):

Convert cell A1 to minutes with: =HOUR(A1)*60+MINUTE(A1)+SECOND(A1)/60.